# How would i replicate this SQL query in Django Rest Framework using generics.ListAPIView and serializers.ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Cant actually find anything like what i am trying to do with wanting to use case statements and left joins using DRF Django Rest Framework, yes this could be done on the front end of the project i am working on but id rather not have to let the front end potentially sending 100s of requests when loading a product list for example.

Nothing i can really add to this but i have tried many different ways of doing the below

```
SELECT 
    p.itemno,
    CASE
        WHEN cp.price IS NULL THEN p.HighSell
        ELSE cp.price
    END AS price
FROM
    api_product AS p
        LEFT JOIN
    api_customerprices AS cp ON p.itemno = cp.itemno
            AND cp.customerno = 'Examplecust'
WHERE
    p.FreeStock > 0
        or restockDate > '1900-01-01'
```

Here Are my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    itemno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    manufacturerCode = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True)
    RRP = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    SSP = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,null=True)
    FreeStock = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ItemSpec1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec6 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec7 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec8 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec9 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    ItemSpec10 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    TI = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    HI = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Item_Height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    Item_Length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    Item_Width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    ProductPaging_Height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    ProductPaging_Length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    ProductPaging_Width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    CartonHeight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    CartonLength = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    CartonWidth = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    palletQty = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    cartonQty = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    restockDate = models.DateField(null=True)
    IPG = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    CatalogueTheme = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    Analysis2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    Electrical_or_Housewares = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    HighSell = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    Analysis1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    Image = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    MarketingText = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    SearchTerms = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ItemVariant = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Categories = models.CharField(max_length=249, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.itemno

class CustomerPrices(models.Model):
    customerNo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    itemno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    startDate = models.DateField()
    endDate = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customerNo
```

Here are my Serializers

```
class OauthProdListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'itemno',
            'description',
            'colour',
            'RRP',
            'SSP',
            'manufacturerCode',
            'FreeStock',
            'restockDate',
            'Image',
            'HighSell',
            'ItemVariant',
            'Categories'
        )

class OCustomerPricesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerPrices
        fields = (
            'id',
            'customerNo',
            'itemno',
            'price'
        )
```

Comment: Do you have some models in django already or do you want to simply execute the raw sql?

Comment: yes the models already exist in my project, i want to know how to execute the equivalent in DRF using those models

Comment: What have you tried in your code so far?

Comment: multiple ways of which i do not have the code for but i cant actually find any documentation on how to replicate something as simple as a case statement or a left join, if you know of a way of doing the above that would be very helpful

Comment: Can you post your models please.

Comment: just updated my question to include the models, bit messy as there are alot of fields in place

Answer (score 1):

Found a way of performing what i wanted, turned out i was missing knowledge on the SerializerMethodField() method, once i found out that i got it pretty quickly.

```
class ProdListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
price = SerializerMethodField()
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = [
        'id',
        'itemno',
        'description',
        'colour',
        'RRP',
        'SSP',
        'manufacturerCode',
        'FreeStock',
        'restockDate',
        'Image',
        'ItemVariant',
        'Categories',
        'price'
    ]

def get_price(self, obj):
    itemno = obj.itemno
    customerNo = self._context['view'].request.query_params.get('customerNo', '')
    if customerNo:
        customerPrice = CustomerPrices.objects.filter(
            Q(customerNo=customerNo) &
            Q(itemno=itemno)
        ).values('price').first()
        if customerPrice:
            return customerPrice
        else:
            return Product.objects.filter(itemno=itemno).values('HighSell').first()
    else:
        return Product.objects.filter(itemno=itemno).values('HighSell').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing this off the top of my head so it will take some effort on your part to get it working.

You do not have a relationship between your Product and CustomerPrices. You will either need to add a Foreignkey between the two tables directly or, you will need to add an intermediate table with foreignkeys between them.
Your query will be something like:

`Q` is a django query object - see [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```py
results = CustomerPrices.objects.filter(
    Q(itemno__FreeStock__gt=0) | Q(itemno__restockDate__gt='1900-0-01'),
    customerno='Examplecust'
)

# Your case statement can be handled in your code logic:

def case_statement(result):
    if not result.price:
        return result.HighSell
    return result.price
```

Comment: Hope this helps, if it does please be kind enough to upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply but im still unsure about how i would use that code within DRF, partly due to experience.

Comment: That is a little more than the scope of a single stackoverflow ticket. I would recommend you take the time to understand the basics of django and DRF otherwise you will constantly be stuck.

Comment: *thanks for your reply but im still unsure about how i would use that code within DRF, partly due to experience like how would i apply that logic per line in the view itself

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean, but you can get the SQL for all the tables in an app by running this command:

```
python manage.py sqlall your_app
```

or you want to convert sql to django use :

```
Person.objects.raw('your_sql_query')
```

Comment: i mean i want to return what the results of that query would be to anyone accessing the data via Django Rest Framework but that being said there is functionality to use objects.raw() but when being ran through the a Serializer it either wont display the fields from the joined table or if you try to specify the fields on the Serializer it will fail because the fields specified on the joined table to not exist on the model, ill update the question to include the seralizers